# distance_of_time_in_words_to_now not accurate

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So, maybe I'm doing this wrong, but in rails 3.2.19, I'm getting this result:

```
irb(main):009:0> include ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper
=> Object
irb(main):009:0> distance_of_time_in_words_to_now(DateTime.now + 1.day)
=> "1 day"
irb(main):010:0> distance_of_time_in_words_to_now(DateTime.now + 1.month)
=> "about 1 month"
irb(main):011:0> distance_of_time_in_words_to_now(DateTime.now + 2.month)
=> "about 1 month"
irb(main):012:0> distance_of_time_in_words_to_now(DateTime.now + 3.month)
=> "3 months"
```

Why does adding 2 months show me `about 1 month`?

Or, can anyone suggest a more accurate natural language date gem or method?

### Solution:

I guess my old-ass version of rails is the problem.  So, I used the [chronic_duration](https://github.com/hpoydar/chronic_duration) gem and ended up with this little snippet:

```
opt = { weeks: true, units: 2, joiner: ' and ' }.merge!(options)
ChronicDuration.output((date_time.to_datetime - DateTime.now).to_i * 24 * 60 * 60, opt)
```

which yields

```
"2 mos and 3 days"
```

Comment: It does say "about", though it really should say "ish".

Comment: Thanks, I blame my old rails version.  Solution provided above.

Comment: @timsabat Great. If you feel it's your old version of rails, could you please mark my answer as the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine for me.

```
[11] pry(main)> include ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper
=> Object

[12] pry(main)> distance_of_time_in_words_to_now(DateTime.now + 1.day)
=> "1 day"

[13] pry(main)> distance_of_time_in_words_to_now(DateTime.now + 1.month)
=> "about 1 month"

[14] pry(main)> distance_of_time_in_words_to_now(DateTime.now + 2.month)
=> "about 2 months"

[15] pry(main)> distance_of_time_in_words_to_now(DateTime.now + 3.month)
=> "3 months"
```

What version of rails are you using? Maybe it was a bug that has been fixed. I am running the 4.2 beta.

Comment: added rails version above.  This is a bummer.

Comment: Seems like a pretty old version. I would recommend looking at the history of https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb and see if there were any fixed that would have corrected the problem you are having.